# SELECT processing speed in SQL from element Position

Tags: mysql

I have 2 columns: column1 (`id`) is primary and column2 (`title`) is not primary (I mean contents of column2 can be repetitive in column2). Then I want to know the selecting speed is the same for the following two lines of code or not ?

Query #1:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE id = '$id' AND title = '$title';
```

Query #2:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE title = '$title' AND id = '$id';
```

Comment: It should be the same. If you really want to know in detail, see at: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/statement-optimization.html

Comment: @KenanZahirovic tnx pal !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two queries should have exactly the same execution plan.  Both conditions are applied at the same time or at least in the same way.

If you want to optimize this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id = '$id' AND title = '$title';
```

Then you can use an index:

```
create index idx_table_id_title on table(id, title)
```

Also, when writing queries in an application, you should use parameters for the queries rather than substituting values directly into the query string.

Comment: uhm, i will creat an index consist of both column1 and column2. only i couldn't understanding your mean of this line: **you should use parameters for the queries rather than substituting values directly into the query string.** may tell me more about that ?

Comment: @Fatemeh . . . You should not be taking user input and putting it directly in a query string.  Instead, you should learn about parameterized queries.  However, the syntax depends on the interface you are using.

Comment: Your mean is that I'm not use this: `id='$id'` . But what can I do? May you tell me a example? Thx buddy